# holder.js not referenced or loaded in html document

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, holder.js

I am new to Bootstrap. As i have started with DashBoard example in BootStrap. i see the below code in html page.

```
<img data-src="holder.js/200x200/auto/vine" class="img-responsive" alt="Generic placeholder thumbnail">
```

And i did a search of entire html code, no where i found holder.js being loaded. Can someone explain me from where does holder.js get loaded ? All i see is the above reference inside a image tag. But i am just wondering where or how will the browser be aware of holder.js

Answer (score 3, accepted):

holder.js is just a client side image placeholder script and not part of Bootstrap nor necessary at all. It is used in development to put in generic placeholder images until you put in your own images

[holder.js](http://imsky.github.io/holder/)

You do not need to load docs.min.js for Bootstrap.

Comment: Agreed. Rather i had to re-phrase my question, stating "understanding the Dashboard Example in BootStrap"

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer after i did a bit of file content search. Holder.js is referenced with a different javascript filename. I am not sure why Bootstrap people have done this !!

```
<script src="../../assets/js/docs.min.js"></script>
```

The above file doc.min.js has all the necessary code that should have been part of holder.js

Comment: Minification and concatenation are common best-practices for production JavaScript deployment. That's why we did it. `docs.min.js` includes other libraries too, not just `holder.js`

Comment: Thanks for that. I did not mean to say you have done wrong. Well that was a best practice learning for me.